# Mouseenter and Mouseleave dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have this dropdown menu to show the submenu when mouse is hover it and stay hover when on top of the submenu as well, but when the mouse leaves, I want it to hide it.

The following link, I was only able to change the javascript to mouseenter, but I don't know how to create the mouseleave function.

It's probably super easy for anyone who knows how to code, but I don't :(

Here is the link: https://codepen.io/ok2ju/pen/MwyvWY

And here is the code:

```
document.querySelector('.mini-photo-wrapper').addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  document.querySelector('.menu-container').classList.toggle('active');
});
```

Comment: copy + paste this block then change where it says `mouseenter` to `mouseleave`

Comment: The only problem with that is the menu does not stay put so I can't select it.

Comment: Without some code showing your issue, it's going to be impossible to debug your problem. My guess, if you're using the codepen link, is that the markup isn't structured such that you would keep your mouse within `.mini-photo-wrapper` and therefore when you `mouseleave`, you're going to trigger the close event. You need to rewrite the HTML for the solution you're aiming for